# Organizar Classes EDMX

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, database-first

Tenho um projeto DB First que utiliza um EDMX para mapear a base de dados. As tabelas possuem colunas padrão que existem em todas elas e que eu poderia organizar e deixar o código bem mais genérico se fosse possível implementar interfaces na mesma com estas propriedades, mas não é uma boa prática alterar as classes geradas automaticamente pelo EDMX.

Há alguma boa prática ou padrão para melhorar a organização e reaproveitamento de código no modelo DB First?

**Atualização**

Vendo que, aparentemente, não existe uma solução direta para este problema, existe, talvez, alguma forma então de fazer com que um código iniciado com CodeFirst mude automaticamente com alguma alteração realizada no banco? (importar as modificações)?

Comment: *"...mas não é uma boa prática alterar as classes geradas automaticamente pelo EDMX"*. Depende. Se o banco é modificado com frequência, não é mesmo. Caso contrário, não há problema. Gostaria de uma resposta considerando o segundo caso?

Comment: Sim, gostaria sim. O banco até não é alterado com frequência, mas toda a vez que fosse alterado ele iria importar novamente as classes e desfazer o que foi feito. Tem como evitar isso?

Comment: Então, mas a minha resposta vai acabar com esse esquema de importação, ok?

Comment: *"[...] mas não é uma boa prática alterar as classes geradas automaticamente pelo EDMX."*. Não é que não seja uma **boa prática**, né. Isso não é uma **boa ideia**, porque, como já foi dito, sempre que mudar o banco essas classes vão ser geradas novamente.

Comment: Sim. Sabendo de todas essas questões, como então eu poderia criar uma solução melhor para este problema, já que não posso usar CodeFirst e o projeto todo já se baseia nessas tabelas importadas?

Comment: Bem interessante sua pergunta, realmente não conheço uma solução "elegante" e matadora para este caso. Mas pesquisando me deparei com algo semelhante ao se tentar implementar MetaDataTypes em classes geradas pelo DB first. Como essas classes são geradas como partial, será que você não poderia criar novas classes parciais também e implementar sua ideia?  No link a seguir tem um exemplo de algo parecido,veja se te ajudar a achar uma direção: Link -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9071120/defining-data-annotation-using-dbcontext-versus-objectcontext-in-the-database-fi/9073286#9073286

Comment: Pois então, este link é útil para colocar propriedades e métodos adicionais a uma classe gerada automaticamente sem perder as modificações, mas no meu caso eu preciso implementar uma interface. Vou testar se é possível fazer isso com MetaDataTypes aqui.

Comment: Existe, talvez, alguma forma então de fazer com que um código iniciado com CodeFirst mude automaticamente com alguma alteração realizada no banco? (importar as modificações)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Descobri que a solução é mais simples do que eu esperava.

```
//Classe gerada automaticamente pelo EF
public partial class BaseClassPartialTests
{
    public string PropTeste1 { get; set; }
    public string PropTeste2 { get; set; }
    public string PropTeste3 { get; set; }
}

//Como a classe gerada pelo EF é uma Partial Class, 
//basta criar, em outro arquivo, uma outra classe parcial herdando da interface que eu quero.
public partial class BaseClassPartialTests : IBaseProps
{
    public BaseClassPartialTests()
    {
        PropTeste1 = PropTeste2 = PropTeste3 = string.Empty;
    }
}

//Interface para aplicar nas classes.
public interface IBaseProps
{
    string PropTeste1 { get; set; }
    string PropTeste2 { get; set; }
}
```

A desvantagem é que eu vou ter que criar uma classe parcial para cada classe gerada automaticamente pelo EF, mas ao aplicar a interface nelas, vai possibilitar deixar todos os meus códigos de acesso a dados bem mais genéricos e menos repetitivos. Inclusive com a possibilidade da criação de construtores.